# Add GeoService to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoservices-rest-api

EDIT: I was able to add the layer in the example below by using the GeoService url, removing 'rest/', after much trial and error. Is there documentation regarding this 'trick', or can someone explain why this works?

Original question:

Is there any way to consume the data from either a GeoJSON or GeoService API url from an ArcGIS Open Data Portal page, into ArcMap (using v. 10.4.1)?

An example would be: [BC OGC Pipelines](http://data-bcogc.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/359b7e14fafa4abc84ff873bc55015fb_0?geometry=-120.907%2C56.536%2C-120.889%2C56.537)

The API section looks like:

[image]

I have seen other ArcGIS Open Data pages that also include a url in the API section for OGC WMS ([example](http://data-cityofpg.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/314bb0ff3e1f43448ed8076f0f17b498_194)), so it may be a conscious decision to not serve data in a format consumable by ArcMap, but I'm not familiar enough with web service protocols to be certain.

Things I have tried:

- adding the GeoService url (full and many shortened versions) through both 'Add ArcGIS Server' and 'Add WMS Server' in 'Add Data'
- adding the layer through 'Add Data from ArcGIS Online'. The dialog finds the layer, I click 'Add', the layer appears in the table of contents, although there appear to be no features (e.g. should be lots of pipelines at 651871E, 6197336N, UTM10).

Comment: The service you reference is not a WMS, therefore you will not be able to treat it as a WMS. Hint WMS supply images, but this is a vector data service

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @nmtoken. I was able to add the 'ArcGIS Map Service' through the 'ArcGIS Server' dialog, using the url listed under 'GeoService', removing the 'rest' component from the url. Clearly I'm not familiar with ArcGIS for Server. Can you explain why it works when I remove 'rest', and where this, what seems like a trick, might be documented?

Comment: Also, if this wasn't what you were hinting at, could you provide a more direct hint at how I could add this type of layer to ArcMap?

Comment: Removing the "rest" from the url typically results in a url that references a SOAP endpoint.  ArcMap is able to consume either REST or SOAP. http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/a-quick-tour-of-using-a-service-in-desktop.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_33D79B7ABD0346869D8EA7FE1DEDFD38

Comment: Aha! Those are the missing pieces: 1.) ArcMap needs a SOAP url (at least, that's what the page says), and 2.) you can derive a SOAP url from a REST url by removing 'rest/'. I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking your given service as an example `https://geoweb.bcogc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/pasr/PASR_PL_SEGMENT_LN/MapServer/0`, I was able to add the service to ArcMap (10.3.1) by specifying the following URL stem `https://geoweb.bcogc.ca/arcgis` when using:

> Add Data > GIS Servers > Add ArcGIS Server > Use GIS services > Server URL

Then selecting one of the listed services

[image: Opening geoweb.bcogc.ca in ArcMap]